# How to get city by latitude and longtitude?

Tags: latitude-longitude, geocode

I need to get city name by latitude and longtitude. (Use xcode)
There is google with itself's api geocode, but it don't want to return nearest city (i need only nearest city) and it returns cyrilic names of places. How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Geonames.org webservice](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) for "Find nearby populated place / reverse geocoding" (scroll a bit down), see [this example](http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName?lat=47.3&lng=9&username=demo).